# I don't know what was a wrong about use UIView.animate or create UIImageView method. I'm use swift language

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have created a module that inherits UIView and moves the image to the left.
Working well at first, but if you enter the screen after moving again, the screen disappears and reappears. (self.present or another tabbarcontroller...)
I'm rolling three images, where is it wrong? Please check the bottom code.
In the code below, after passing the image parameters to setImage, it is executed by startAnimate ().
I also upload videos, please help.

https://youtu.be/I9AJrt-SWF0

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class DisolveBanner: UIView {

    private var bannerImage = [String]()
    private var bannerStr = [String]()
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var num: Int = 0
    private var numNow: Int = 0

    var timerInterval: Double = 5.0
    var disolveInterval: Double = 1.0
    var rangeMove: CGFloat = 100

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // -MARK: Setting Images
    func setImage(images: [String], str: [String]) {

        if images.isEmpty == false && images.count == str.count {
            bannerImage.removeAll()
            bannerImage = images

            bannerStr.removeAll()
            bannerStr = str

            num = (bannerImage.count) - 1
        }
    }

    // -MARK: Start Animation
    func startAnimate() {

        if bannerImage.isEmpty == false {
            autoAnimate()
            timer = Timer()
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (timerInterval - disolveInterval),
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(autoAnimate),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
        }
    }

    // -MARK: Finish Animation
    func stopAnimate() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    @objc private func  autoAnimate() {

        moveImage(image: bannerImage[numNow], str: bannerStr[numNow])

        if numNow < num {
            numNow = numNow + 1
        } else {
            numNow = 0
        }
    }

    private func moveImage(image: String?, str: String?) {

        if let img = image {

            let imgWidth = self.frame.size.width + rangeMove
            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgWidth, height: self.frame.size.height))
            imgView.frame.origin.x = 0
            imgView.alpha = 0.2
            imgView.setKingfisher(image: img)
            self.addSubview(imgView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: disolveInterval) {
                self.imgView.alpha = 1.0
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: timerInterval, animations: {
                self.imgView.frame.origin.x = (0 - self.rangeMove)
            }) { (finished) in
                self.imgView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        if let msg = str {

            let msgView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
            msgView.frame.origin.x = 0
            msgView.alpha = 0.2
            msgView.text = msg
            msgView.sizeToFit()
            msgView.textColor = UIColor.white
            self.addSubview(msgView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: timerInterval, animations: {
                msgView.alpha = 1.0
            }) { (finished) in
                msgView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you use DisolveBanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot to take in first, so I cannot give you the exact solution, but here are some things to look at:

**When your viewController disappers, the animators stop.** Maybe the timer too. So that's clue number one. You might want to override viewDidAppear and restart your animations either from the beginning, or if you are keeping track of the state, then from wherever it stopped. It is clear on the video, that when your timer ticks the first time it starts the animation.
`var timerInterval: Double = 5.0`
Rather you should start it right when the viewDidAppear or when the viewWillAppear (that should work too).

**Other thing is; viewDidLoad will not be called on your tab bar items for the second time, only for the first time.**
When you have too many states and completion handles asynchronously and they rely on each other to share some data and you disrupt that by stopping all of them (Application does rather), these things happen, generally handle disappearing, and appearing of the viewController, dont rely on viewDidLoad

**Third thing to look at:** You might need to check, what happens when the application entersBackground, or entersAppSwitcher or reachability is engaged, those are the next cases when things will go wrong.